# How can I set up DNS for my website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, dns

I have a specific DNS problem for my website - I can access my website using its static ip address but not its domain name. Here's a description of my situation:

1. I registered a website name, say, "xxx.com", at GoDaddy.com, but the web app is hosted on a AWS lightsail Ubuntu instance with a static ip;
2. In the "DNS Management" page of this same  on GoDaddy.com, I specified custom name servers as those provided by AWS
3. On AWS Lightsail, I then created an "A" DNS record that maps "xxx.com" to the ubuntu instance's static ip: "A" - "xxx.com" -> "x.x.x.x"
4. I was able to reach my website using "xxx.com" last night, but after rebooting the Ubuntu instance this morning, the domain name is unreachable while the website can still be accessed using its ip address

I have 2 questions -

1. How would AWS' name servers know that I am the rightful owner of this purchased domain name "xxx.com", by allowing me to map "xxx.com" to a certain ip address?
2. Did I miss something during the process above that made my website unreachable today using "xxx.com"? Why was it working yesterday but not today??

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Give the true names involved, do not use useless obfuscation, especially when not following RFC2606 to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I can now partially answer my own question #2, and the answer is DNS propagation.

When DNS changes are made, it might take up to 24 hours for the DNS changes to take effect across the internet. Both name servers and one's local DNS cache will need to refresh first before receiving newly changed DNS records.

Comment: "propagation" is not really the answer, even if it is a term often used, it is technically wrong. However indeed when you do DNS changes you need to wait "some time" before the changes appear everywhere. You can find many posts including here that talk about that.